# Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor

Tags: python, opencv

I am running the following code snippet on a test video. The code runs the starting frames without problem but at one point starts giving the following error

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor

Here is the code snippet.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test/Pedestrian overpass.mp4')
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test/dark1.mp4')

if (cap.isOpened() == False):
    print("Error opening video stream / file")
    exit(0)
else:
    print("Hello")
    ret , frame0 = cap.read()
    prevFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

trying this:

```
  ret , frame0 = cap.read()
    if not frame0 is None:
        prevFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: i am still getting the same error :(